# Missing total page size in Safari Web Inspector

Tags: safari, safari-web-inspector

In Safari Web Inspector it is not possible to measure total page size because immediately after page is loaded this value is disappearing. How can I make it persistent (still visible after page is loaded)?

I have the same problem in both: Safari 11.0.1 and Safari Developer Preview 44.
[Please look on attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ82E.png)

BR
Arek

Comment: Hi @ArekS , Do u find the reason of it. am also facing the same!

Comment: Hi Mohanraj, No I still did not find a reason :(